# USB-C monitor on PinebookPro is not working

Tags: usb, display, external-monitor, usb-c

i'm not totally new to Ubuntu/Linux but still far from being a pro!
Actually i run Ubuntu 22.04 (installed via ARMBIAN) with Gnome 42 on my Pinebook Pro ARM-Laptop:

```
$lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
    
$ uname -a
    Linux pinebook-pro 6.1.30-rockchip64 #3 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 24 16:32:53 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
$ gnome-shell --version
 GNOME Shell 42.
```

I've tried an Dell Monitor with USB-C-Support (U3421WE) an DELL-USB-C- Dockingstation with a Lenovo-Monitor and a Lenovo Thinkpas Universal USB-C-Dock (40AY) with an Fujitsu Monitor.

The beahviour ist always the same: USB-Hub is Working (Mous, & Keyboard etc.) but Display is not:

The U3421WE display,: " No USB-C Signal from the Divce". The other ones yust say: "No input Signal".
It makes no difference if it is hotplugged or plugged in befor boot also not flipping the USBC plug.

Her ist (as an example) some information i imagine to be helpful:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 015: ID 17ef:30a9 Lenovo 40AY
Bus 007 Device 017: ID 17ef:30b0 Lenovo ThinkPad USB-C Dock Audio
Bus 007 Device 020: ID 046d:c069 Logitech, Inc. M-U0007 [Corded Mouse M500]
Bus 007 Device 019: ID 046a:010d Cherry GmbH MX-Board 3.0 Keyboard
Bus 007 Device 018: ID 17ef:30ae Lenovo USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 007 Device 016: ID 17ef:30ac Lenovo USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 007 Device 014: ID 17ef:30af Lenovo USB2.0 Hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6321 Microdia HP Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 258a:001e HAILUCK CO.,LTD USB KEYBOARD
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


$ lsusb -v -s 007:15
Bus 007 Device 015: ID 17ef:30a9 Lenovo 40AY
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.01
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x17ef Lenovo
  idProduct          0x30a9 
  bcdDevice           30.80
  iManufacturer           1 Lenovo
  iProduct                2 40AY
  iSerial                 3 1S40AY0090EUZVR01WKQ
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0029
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass        17 
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              5 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      3 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              6 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        
        
  $ sudo lshw -c display
  *-graphics                
       Produkt: rockchipdrmfb
       Physische ID: d
       Logischer Name: /dev/fb0
       Fähigkeiten: fb
       Konfiguration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080

$ sudo dmesg -C    
$ sudo dmesg -H 
[Jul19 12:00] usb 7-1: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci-hcd
[  +0,162850] usb 7-1: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=30af, bcdDevice=60.90
[  +0,000025] usb 7-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=0
[  +0,000008] usb 7-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[  +0,000006] usb 7-1: Manufacturer: Lenovo
[  +0,045558] hub 7-1:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0,000339] hub 7-1:1.0: 3 ports detected
[  +0,287217] usb 7-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci-hcd
[  +0,102859] usb 7-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=30a9, bcdDevice=30.80
[  +0,000026] usb 7-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0,000008] usb 7-1.3: Product: 40AY
[  +0,000006] usb 7-1.3: Manufacturer: Lenovo
[  +0,000006] usb 7-1.3: SerialNumber: 1S40AY0090EUZVR01WKQ
[  +0,285455] usb 7-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci-hcd
[  +0,103629] usb 7-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=30ac, bcdDevice=51.14
[  +0,000026] usb 7-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0,000008] usb 7-1.1: Product: USB2.0 Hub             
[  +0,000007] usb 7-1.1: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[  +0,000006] usb 7-1.1: SerialNumber: 000000001
[  +0,052349] hub 7-1.1:1.0: USB hub found
[  +0,000125] hub 7-1.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  +0,411473] usb 7-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 20 using xhci-hcd
[  +0,118560] usb 7-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=30b0, bcdDevice= 0.42
[  +0,000024] usb 7-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0,000008] usb 7-1.2: Product: ThinkPad USB-C Dock Audio
```